# How to covert time "now-5m" to datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a scenario where i can get date time in any of the following format.

1) as string in following format : 1970-01-01T00:00:00

2) "now-5m"

3) "now-1h"

or similar combinations with min, second or even day, I want to get a time which is x min older than this given time, What would be the best way to do so ? Is there any library present which can handle all these formats and give me datetime in some uniform format?

Comment: is "now" actually a string? I mean, is your input exactly "now - 5m"?

Comment: @LanteDellarovere Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing more research i figured out there is a module called dateparser which provides a parse method, using parse method we can convert any format into datetime.datetime object and then we can subtract using relativedelta method as prosti suggested.

Sample code

```
import dateparser
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print(dateparser.parse("now"))
print(dateparser.parse("now-30s"))
print(dateparser.parse("now-5m"))
print(dateparser.parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00"))
print(dateparser.parse("1970/01/01T00:00:00"))
print(type(dateparser.parse("1970/01/01T00:00:00")))
dt = dateparser.parse("now-5m")
print(dt - relativedelta(minutes=10)) # equals to now -15 min
```

output::

2019-05-06 12:55:54.074220

2019-05-06 12:55:24.076534

2019-05-06 12:50:54.077823

1970-01-01 00:00:00

1970-01-01 00:00:00

2019-05-06 12:40:54.087881

you can read more at :: https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/

Comment: Great, in that case you can accept your own answer :) Or any other answer which helped you the most! Entirely upto you @TajUddin

Comment: Sure, Thanks Devesh.

Comment: Nice! didn't know about this module, thanks! (Answerer say thanks to the questioner for the answer, nice spot)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at the `datetime` module of python. We use the [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the datetime string to datetime object, then use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to do the operations like subtracting minutes and hours

```
import datetime

#Convert the string to datetime object
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('1970-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

#Subtract 5 minutes from the time
print(dt - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))

#Subtract 1 hour from the time
print(dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=1))
```

The output will be `1969-12-31 23:55:00`

In addition, you can also look at [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library which gives you [dateutil.relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) in which you can provide years, days and months as well

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#Convert the string to datetime object
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('1970-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

#Subtract 5 minutes from the time
print(dt - relativedelta(days=5))

#Subtract 1 hour from the time
print(dt - relativedelta(month=1))
```

The output here will be

```
1969-12-27 00:00:00
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Now in order to avoid having to provide `hours,minutes,days` etc as argument, you can convert all of them into a standard format (say `seconds` and `minutes`), and then use that.

So e.g if you want to subtract an hour and 5 minutes, you can just subtract 65 minutes

```
#Subtract 65 minutes from the time
print(dt - relativedelta(minutes=5))

#Subtract 1 hour and 5 minutes from the time
print(dt - relativedelta(hours=1, minutes=5))
```

Maybe you can write a function which gets a string like `5m`, `1h`, `2d` as input and give you minutes in return

```
def get_minutes(s):

    if 'm' in s:
        return int(s.replace('m',''))

    elif 'h' in s:
        return int(s.replace('h', ''))*60

    elif 'd' in s:
        return int(s.replace('d', ''))*1440

print(get_minutes('5m'))
#5
print(get_minutes('1h'))
#60
print(get_minutes('2d'))
#2880
```

Then you can use this in your `timedelta` or `relativedelta` function, perhaps expand this function to include more types of time strings
Similarly you can come up with a standard time which you convert all your times to, and then use that in the argument!

Comment: What about case 2 and 3 ? i want to handle all the case using some uniform code ? 1970-01-01T00:00:00 is just one possible value, it could be "now-30s" or "not-1d" as well, and i don't want to handle all the cases manually.

Comment: Case 2 and 3 are posted, and for any other case, you can specify the parameters in the `datetime.timedelta` accordingly?

Comment: the probalem is if do that manually there are so many options, s , m, h, d, w, m or so, i will have to manually check what is magnitude and unit and then based on that convert that to eqvalent timedelta format, i am trying to avoid that.

Comment: In that case, may I suggest converting all those options into a standard time format e.g. all into seconds and then use datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)  @TajUddin

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, modified your example a bit. More compact: )

Comment: @Devesh, This look pretty generic problem to me, i believe there must be some library which will be doing same thing. instead of me doing all this poor man stuff. Just hoping, otherwise i will have to do that anyway.

Comment: If you think in a way, you are just passing a number to the function, how will it know whether it is supposed to represent an hour, a day or a minute. It is upto you to tell the function what the number is, does that make sense @TajUddin ?

Comment: Sure @prosti You can always refer to my answer using https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003659/8591431

Comment: No worries, I updated my answer to have the link you provided. I will check some other answers of yours and provide some workarounds, tweaks etc. Great way to learn @DeveshKumarSingh.

Comment: sure thing @prosti Just don't get my answers unaccepted haha! jk :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003659/8591431) like this:

```
import datetime

#Convert the string to datetime object
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('1970-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

#Subtract one hour and 5 minutes together :)
print(dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=5))
```

It returns:

```
1969-12-31 22:55:00
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea for 2), 3) cases, to be tested and refined:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def fuzzy_parse(t): return dt.datetime.utcnow() - pd.Timedelta(t.split("-")[1])

print(dt.datetime.utcnow(), fuzzy_parse("now-1s"))
print(dt.datetime.utcnow(), fuzzy_parse("now-1m"))
print(dt.datetime.utcnow(), fuzzy_parse("now-1h"))
print(dt.datetime.utcnow(), fuzzy_parse("now-1d"))
print(dt.datetime.utcnow(), fuzzy_parse("now-1w"))
```

Output:

```
2019-05-06 11:24:12.347120 2019-05-06 11:24:11.347125
2019-05-06 11:24:12.347388 2019-05-06 11:23:12.347391
2019-05-06 11:24:12.347554 2019-05-06 10:24:12.347557
2019-05-06 11:24:12.347710 2019-05-05 11:24:12.347712
2019-05-06 11:24:12.347863 2019-04-29 11:24:12.347865
```